# Find equations for the two lines through the point (3, 13) that are tangent to the parabola $y = 6x - x^2. $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, slope

Find equations for the two lines through the point (3, 13) that are tangent to the parabola $y = 6x - x^2$

since both lines must be tangent to the parabola their slope must  be:

$$y' = 6- 2x$$

so.

$$6-2x = \frac{y-13}{x-3}$$
$$y = 12x-2x^2-5$$

but I did not get the lines what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that the numbers $x$ and $y$ are not arbitrary; they are such that $y=6x-x^2$. So, since $y$ is equal to both $6x-x^2$ and to $12x-2x^2-5$, you have $6x-x^2=12x-2x^2-5$. This is a quadratic equation, whose solutions are $1$ and $5$. It follows that the points of the parabola that you are after are $(1,5)$ and $(5,5)$.

Comment: What about the equations of the two lines in the form y=mx+b

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: you are given me points but I am looking for lines

Comment: The line passing through $(1,5)$ and $(3,13)$ is $-4x+y=1$, where is the line passing through $(5,5)$ and $(3,13)$ is $4x+y=25$.

Comment: how do you find it?

Comment: The slope of the line passing through $(1,5)$ and $(3,13)$ is $\frac{13-5}{5-3}=4$, and the line passing through $(1,5)$ whose slope is $4$ is $y=4(x-1)+5=4x+1$. The other one is similar.

Comment: I only get the point 1 and 5 not 5,5?

Comment: If $x=1$, then, since $y=6x-x^2$, $y=5$, and therefore $(x,y)=(1,5)$. The same argument applies to $x=5$.